# operator <= overloading for 2 classes and converting ctor

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

I have a little problem, which the Visual Studio compiler don't seem to be bothered by, but do in eclipse and g++.

I have 2 classes, Card and CardDeck. I do have the operator <= for 2 Carddecks as parameters and do not for 2 cards. I have a converting ctor, which converts Card to a Deck.

So the problem is when I do:

```
card1 <= card2
```

Which does work fine in visual, as it converts the left part to deck, then converts the right and then does the comparing.

In g++ it says:

```
no match for 'operator<=' (operand types are 'Card' and 'Card')
```

But there shouldn't be one. as I said I want the convert ctor would convet both sides and do the compare?

Any explanation and solution for this ?

**Edit(the operator and ctor declaration and code):**

```
CardDeck(const Card&);
friend bool operator<=(const CardDeck&, const CardDeck&);

CardDeck::CardDeck(const Card& card){
    _Deck.push_back(card);
}
```

Comment: Code says more than a thousand words. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Is your `operator<=` a member or non-member?

Comment: non-member as friend

Comment: I assume you mean `operator<=` and not `operator==` in the added declarations?

Comment: fixed it. So my question is, is this a normal behavor of the g++ compiler (C11) and if I want it compare 2 cards I must manually cast one of the components to CardDeck or is it my bad in y code ?

Comment: And what is mostly weird, that for any other operators <, >, >=, which are realized using <= it's ok even with comparation 2 cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick&dirty of what I think you are trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Element
{
    int x;
    Element() :x(0) {}
    virtual ~Element() {}
};

struct Container
{
    Element elems[10];
    int n;
    Container() { n=0; }
    Container(const Element &e) { elems[0]=e; n=1; }
    virtual ~Container() {}
    friend bool operator<=(const Container &l, const Container &r);
};

bool operator<=(const Container &l, const Container &r)
{
    if (l.n<=r.n) { std::cout << "less/equ\n"; return true; }
    else { std::cout << "greater\n"; return false; }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    //Container container;
    Element a, b;
    if (a<=b) std::cout << "okay\n"; else std::cout << "fail\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine with gcc.

Comment: Seems that what I've wrote should work too in that case, very strange. I really don't see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
Deck(card1) <= Deck(card2)
```

Make `operator<= (operand types are 'Card' and 'Card')` override cause you use(mean) that in `card1 <= card2` expression. Your code have architecture errors.

---

**Update**:

```
struct Card
{
    bool operator<( const Card& right ) const;
};

struct Deck
{
    std::vector<Card> m_arr;

    Deck() = default;
    Deck( const Card& conversion )
    {
        m_arr.push_back( conversion );
    }
    bool operator<( const Deck& right ) const;
};

bool Card::operator<( const Card& right ) const
{
    return false;
}
bool Deck::operator<( const Deck& right ) const
{
    bool result = false;
    if(m_arr.size() < right.m_arr.size())
    {
        result = true;
    }
    else if(!m_arr.empty() && m_arr.size() == right.m_arr.size() )
    {
        result = true;
        std::vector<Card>::const_iterator it = right.m_arr.begin();
        std::vector<Card>::const_iterator it2 = m_arr.begin();
        for(; it2 != m_arr.end(); ++it, ++it2 )
        {
            if((*it) < (*it2))
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: As I wrote in the other comment, all the other compare operators, which only use <= are work fine with card on each side of the equation. How can I fix it ?

Comment: @KittyT2016 and how do you explain logically the comparison with a deck of cards ...?

Comment: deck1 <= deck2 if every card in deck1 is in deck2 (deck2 can have all cards of deck1 and more).

Comment: @KittyT2016 updated answer - compare T1 and T2 is semantice right, in other case check equals T1 and U2 is strongly incorrect in many cases.